# Why I obtain this runtime error when I try to inject a repository into a controller class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

I am finding some problem using the **@Autowired** annotation to inject an instance of a repository class (that implements a DAO) into another class.

So I have my repository class named **KMProjectInfoServiceImpl**:

```
@Repository("kmProjectInfoService")
public class KMProjectInfoServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements KMProjectInfoService {


    public List<KM_ProjectInfo> getProjectInfoList() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().execute(
                new HibernateCallback<List<KM_ProjectInfo>>() {
                    public List<KM_ProjectInfo> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                        return getProjectsInformationsList(session);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public List<KM_ProjectInfo> getProjectInfoListByFolderTech() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().execute(
                new HibernateCallback<List<KM_ProjectInfo>>() {
                    public List<KM_ProjectInfo> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                        return getProjectsInformationsListByFolderTech(session);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public KM_ProjectInfo getProjectInfobyId(long idProjectInfo) {
        final Long id = idProjectInfo;
        return getHibernateTemplate().execute(
                new HibernateCallback<KM_ProjectInfo>() {
                    public KM_ProjectInfo doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                        return getProjectInfo(id, session);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void save(KM_ProjectInfo projectInfo) {
        // L'oggetto non è già presente sulla tabella
        if(projectInfo.getIdProjectInfo() == null){
            getHibernateTemplate().persist(projectInfo);    // lo rende persistente
        }
        // L'oggetto è già presente sulla tabella
        else {
            getHibernateTemplate().merge(projectInfo);      // fa l'update
        }
    }


    private List<KM_ProjectInfo> getProjectsInformationsList(Session session) {
        // Create query:
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("kmProjectInfoList");
        List<KM_ProjectInfo> projectInfoList =  query.list();
        return projectInfoList;
    }

    private List<KM_ProjectInfo> getProjectsInformationsListByFolderTech(Session session) {
        // Create query:
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("kmProjectInfoByFolderTech");
        List<KM_ProjectInfo> projectInfoList =  query.list();
        return projectInfoList;
    }

    private KM_ProjectInfo getProjectInfo(Long id, Session session) {
        // Create query:
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("kmProjectInfoById");
        query.setParameter("projectInfoId", id);
        KM_ProjectInfo projectInfo = (KM_ProjectInfo) query.uniqueResult();
        return projectInfo;
    }
}
```

As you can see this class is annoted using the **@Repository** annotation giving the **kmProjectInfoService** name to my repository, in this way:

```
@Repository("kmProjectInfoService")
```

So now I have to inject this repository into a controller class named **ConfigurationProjectAction** that have to use it as a dependency.

So I have something like this:

```
@Controller("confProjectActionController")
@Scope("prototype")
public class ConfigurationProjectAction extends KMAction implements PortletPreferencesAware {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("kmProjectInfoService")
    private KMProjectInfoServiceImpl

    ................................................
    ................................................
    ................................................
    ................................................
}
```

As you can see in the previous snippet I am trying to use **@Autowired** annotation to inject the repository having specified name as **kmProjectInfoService** (using the **@Qualifier** annotation).

My IDE does not mark errors and I have not compile time error but when I try to execute my application I obtain the following error message into the stacktrace:

```
2015-01-08 10:07:29,321 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR commons.CommonsLogger.error(38) - Could not execute action
Unable to instantiate Action, confProjectActionController,  defined for 'startConfigurationProjectAction' in namespace '/configProject'Error creating bean with name 'confProjectActionController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private egp.prc.km.services.KMProjectInfoServiceImpl egp.prc.km.actions.configurationProject.ConfigurationProjectAction.kmProjectInfoServiceRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [egp.prc.km.services.KMProjectInfoServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=kmProjectInfoService)}
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:318)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:399)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:198)

    ..........................................................................
    ..........................................................................
    ..........................................................................
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private egp.prc.km.services.KMProjectInfoServiceImpl egp.prc.km.actions.configurationProject.ConfigurationProjectAction.kmProjectInfoServiceRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [egp.prc.km.services.KMProjectInfoServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=kmProjectInfoService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)

    ..........................................................................
    ..........................................................................
    ..........................................................................
```

Why? What could be the cause of this error? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it and inject my repository into my controller class?

Comment: Nothing more in stacktrace?

Comment: You need to program to interfaces not concrete classes. Change `KMProjectInfoServiceImpl` to `KMProjectInfoService`.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, and have I to use Qualifier annotation to specify what is the concrete implementation to use?

Comment: No , unless you have multiple imlpementations of the same interface.

Comment: provide your applicationcontext.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject not the implementation of the interface KMProjectInfoService, but the interface directly. Also I'd recommend to remove name of repository on annotation level:

`@Repository("kmProjectInfoService")`

Instead of it use `@Repository`

After this your interface can be used for injection, because it not overlapped with name of repository implementation.

Spring uses proxy pattern for injection. Hence you need to inject interfaces.

Comment: Spring is the one who injects, not the developer. What do you mean by _Spring uses proxy pattern for injection_? I don't see what proxies have to do with injection.

Comment: @zeroflagL The Spring framework makes it possible to intercept method calls to a given bean, provided that bean implements some interface. The Spring framework wraps the bean in a dynamic proxy. All calls to the bean are then intercepted by the proxy. The proxy can decide to call other methods on other objects either before, instead of, or after delegating the method call to the bean wrapped.

Comment: I know, but that still does not explain your suggested connection to dependency injection. It's also worth noting that proxies can be created without interfaces and they are only created when necessary. Spring doesn't create a proxy for every bean.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired wires byType default. So if you have only one matching bean in spring container you no need to use @Qualifier. try below.

```
@Autowired
//@Qualifier("kmProjectInfoService")
private KMProjectInfoService kmProjectInfoService;
```